# Why navigation bar is not showing in angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am learning Angular by Maximilian Schwarzmuller's udemy course. In which he creates a navigation bar. I am also using same code for creating navigation bar but I am not getting expected output. Everything else apart from this is working fine.

```
<nav class ="navbar navbar-default">
<div class ="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a href ="#" class ="navbar-brand">Recipe Book</a>
    </div>

     <div class ="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class ="nav navbar-nav">
         <li><a href="#"> Recipes </a></li>
         <li><a href="#"> Shopping List</a></li>
        </ul>   
        <ul class ="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class ="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class = "dropdown-toggle" role = "button">Manage <span class = "caret"></span></a>
                <ul class = "dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Save Data</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Fetch Data</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

TypeScript Code

```
import { Component, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html'
})

export class HeaderComponent {
    
  }
```

There is no CSS code used.

HTML bar in which navbar is loaded

```
<app-header></app-header>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <app-recipes></app-recipes>
      <app-shopping-list></app-shopping-list>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Expected Output
[image]

My output
[image]

Can someone please help me to find what is issue with the code?

Comment: Plz show the complete code including the ts file of this component, and the html file in which u loaded this navbar

Comment: see the console for possible errors, see if your CSS files are loaded as expected, this looks like a bootstrap thing

Comment: @GahanVig I have uploaded all details, please check

Comment: @DeepakJha There no error in console, also for  navigation bar, there is no CSS file

Comment: what about class ="navbar navbar-default" this, are you sure CSS files holding these classes are loading?

Comment: Without some sort of styles there's no way you can expect your navbar to look, well, styled. I agree with @DeepakJha that it looks like your project is missing some sort of framework with built-in styles. Given the classes you have applied, it's either [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) or a bootstrap-like framework. Search the course for something about adding in bootstrap css.

Comment: @DeepakJha no CSS file have been used in the course until now

Comment: there you go, I am sure there has to be some, check the repository used in this tutorial and look for some CSS framework

Comment: @Dean I have downloaded bootstrap and added in "angular.json"                                  
 "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "src/styles.css"
            ],

Comment: @DeepakJha I have downloaded bootstrap and added in "angular.json"                                  
 "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "src/styles.css"
            ],

Comment: When you say "downloaded" what do you mean? Did you run `npm install --save bootstrap` (assuming you're using NPM)? Did you verify that the css exists in that path in your node_modules? This is starting to become less like a SO question and more like something you should ask the course designer.

Comment: @Dean Yes, I did run "npm install --save bootstrap". How to  verify css exist in that path in my node_modules?

Comment: @Rajeev Try adding "styles": [ "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css", "src/styles.css" ] in angular.json

Answer (score 0):

You should add "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css", "src/styles.css"  in the styles in angular.json file and it should now work

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your navbar is not displaying is because Bootstrap 4 is almost a complete rewrite of Bootstrap 3. In other words, the two versions are completely incompatible.

use the below command and the navbar should be starting to work

1. First uninstall the bootstrap already installed version
   npm uninstall bootstrap
2. Install the bootstrap again using
   "**npm i bootstrap@3**"

This solution has worked for me and the nav bar is now working